# Insert 1-D array into tensor based on an indexing from another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I´ve got three tensors such as:

```
import keras as K
R=K.zeros((4,4))  # tensor where I want to insert 1-D arrays
T=K.constant([0,1,2,3]) #tensor with indexes where I should replace in R
V=K.constant([[1,1,0,0],[4,3,2,0],[2,1,0,0],[3,2,1,0]])  #tensor with 1-D arrays

# do something

# result
'''
array([[1,1,0,0],     <- insert [1,1,0,0] at index 0 
       [0,4,3,2],     <- insert [4,3,2,0] at index 1 
       [0,0,2,1],     <- insert [2,1,0,0] at index 2 
       [0,0,0,3]      <- insert [3,2,1,0] at index 2 
]])
'''
```

It's ok if we lose some elements in the 1-D array if dimensions are exceeded. 
Any thoughts? I´m using tensorflow1.8.0

Comment: You've initiated an array `R` and you want to fill it with the arrays in the tensor `V`, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, but based on the index in tensor T.